# Notice: Undefined index Error When uploaded file size is too long

Tags: php

When I try to post my form ( using ajax ) I got error

> Notice: Undefined index: prepared_object

[image: This is my console log]

And this is the portion of my function which takes that action

```
    public function saveASpotAction(Request $request){

    $place_id = isset($_POST['place_id'])&&!empty($_POST['place_id'])?$_POST['place_id']:0;

    $prepared_object_decoded = json_decode($_POST['prepared_object']);

    if($prepared_object_decoded->add_method=='duplicate_travel_card')
    {
        $save_response_array = $this->duplicateTravelcard();
    }
    else if($place_id)
    {
        $save_response_array = $this->saveASpotOnEdit();
    }
    else
    {
        $save_response_array = $this->saveASpotOnNew();
    }
```

In the post request the variable have a value, and still it shows the error. 
But it work fine when there is no images or a very images uploaded with the request and that feels strange to me.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: I updated the question with the code @ FrankerZ

Comment: What framework are you using? My guess is `$_POST` variables don't work the same way. Your post variables should be a part of `$request`.

Comment: @FrankerZ  Symfony 2.7

Answer (score 0):

At last I found the solution, Its becuause of maximum post size in server settings, It was 20M, And when the uploaded file size is get over that allocated size the variabled will not get on server, I increased it to 1024M, Not Its working ..